# Can You Use Create a System using Glyph of Warding to Cast Teleporation Circle all 365 Days

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

Just curious if there's some ingenious way to set up several *glyph of warding* spells to activate simultaneously. Some of them cast *teleportation circle*, Some of them to receive *glyph of warding* and store a casted *teleportation circle*.

In this way in 365 days you can enjoy a cheap efficient circle with the mats of but a few while exploring?

Comment: This question is very confusing. You have very little detail on the specifics of how you would plan to do this, and your phrasing is hard to follow. I would edit to help, but its just confusing enough that I can not tell what exactly you are asking. Please edit this to add more detail and clarity to this question.

Comment: @Smart_TJ The idea is to do: something something, cast *glyph of warding*, something something, *glyph of warding activates*, something something, now you've got two *glyph of warding* of the first type ready to go, or one *glyph of warding* back and some other effect happened.  It's a classic problem, ifaik yet unsolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can do it manually

By casting Glyph of Warding with a 5th level slot you can load it with Teleportation Circle. You could certainly pre-prepare 365 charged glyphs to create a permanent circle.

### You can't automated it

However, there is no way to store 2 spells and thus no way to cast a new Glyph of Warding charged Teleportation Circle.

### GM fiat

Of course, your GM could rule that a super charged version of Glyph of Warding could be made that takes 2 spells, and can be used as a magical factory. That would definitely be a cool thing to have in a wizard's sanctuary. Obviously a spell like that would be incredibly powerful, you could load it with all kinds of spells to make permanent effects, so any attempt to balance or use it must be restrained.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil I cut down that part to remove possibility of debate ("but what if I trigger it with a corpse??"), there's no way to store 2 spells so that should be the end of the plan.